# Can I use http://myapp.com as URLScheme for my ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, url-scheme

I want to register "http://myapp.com" as custom URLScheme for my ios app. Is it possible? Is it a valid URLScheme?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, the schema is the URL part before the domain-part `myapp.com` - in your case `http`. That schema is obviously already taken.

You need to create a new own schema for your needs like `myapp` which will result in you beeing able to type `myapp://` into safari and make your app pop up.

Two useful links I found via quick googling:

- https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile/url-schemes
- http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

Comment: How a youtube video url, pasted in notes, opens directly in YouTube app instead of safari?

Comment: Because YouTube is special ;)

Comment: What is so special about i?. It's a normal ios app.

Comment: Youtube is special in a way that for example apple lists it in their overview of iOS url schemes https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

[image: set your custom url]

open in safari, your app will be opened.